# Why my Perl CGI script display not rendered html code(not source), instead of page?

Tags: html, perl, apache, cgi

My perl script displays rendered code, when i run it from shtml

```
<!--#include virtual="/cgi-bin/Script.cgi"-->
```

When i run it directly from adress field(site.com/cgi-bin/Script.cgi), i see html code. Why does it happen?
Thanks.

Comment: Put

    AddType text/html .shtml .cgi

to .htaccess. Problem solved.

Answer (score 5):

Because the include operator does not run your CGI program, it substitutes the text of the cgi program in place of the include tag.

You want the exec tag.

```
   <!--#exec cgi="/cgi-bin/Script.cgi" -->
```

Note: the exec tag may be disabled by your server configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Because your script isn't setting a `Content-Type` of `text/html`.